# IntegrityError not raised on None

Tags: python, django, nonetype, data-integrity

I have a model with the following unique constraints:

```
class Record(Model):
    type = ForeignKey(Type, related_name='records')
    code = CharField(max_length=32)
    group = ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='members')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('type', 'code', 'group')
```

I want two records to be the same if they both have the same type and code, and both have no group. I expect an integrity error to be raised, but this does not happen in the following test case:

```
Record.objects.create(type=type_article_structure,
                      code='shoe',
                      group=None)
Record.objects.create(type=type_article_structure,
                      code='shoe',
                      group=None)
```

The unique constraint is working if I fill the same group for both:

```
group = Record.objects.create(type=type_article_structure,
                              code='group')
Record.objects.create(type=type_article_structure,
                      code='shoe',
                      group=group)
Record.objects.create(type=type_article_structure,
                      code='shoe',
                      group=group)
```

This results in:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: md_masterdata_record.type_id, md_masterdata_record.code, md_masterdata_record.group_id
```

How can I make sure that I get the same error in the first case?

PS. My test cases use SQLite, my production server uses PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unique together constraint is applied at the database level. Many databases do not compare `null` values each other and hence, let the insert operations to go in.

You can fix it by overriding `clean` method in your model. `clean` method should be used to provide custom validation or to modify field values before saving. Also, note clean`is not invoked when you call`save`on the object. It should be invoked before calling the`save` method.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
class Record(Model):
    def clean(self):
        # check if exists
        if Record.objects.get(type=self.type,
                          code=self.code,
                          group=self.group):
              # raise an exception
              raise ValidationError("Exists")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand the example. Shouldn't that code be inside a method?

Comment: I forgot to write the method signature :)

Comment: I still don't understand then. Of course, the string 'shoe' is an example, and should not be hardcoded. Do I have access in this method to `self.code` etc.?

Comment: @physicalattraction I have updated the answer with more description and cleaned up the code sample.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I think I will add a similar validation to the RecordManager's `create` method instead, so I don't have to call clean every time I am saving a Record.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
try:
    //somthing
except IntegrityError as e:
    print("integrity")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`
```

2)Check it

```
record=Record(type=type_article_structure,
                  code='shoe',
                  group=None)
record.save()
```